# Running pytest test cases from within the test script

Tags: python, emacs, pytest

All the pytest documentation out there specifies that `py.test file_name` is the standard way for running pytest test cases. But I develop in Emacs with the Python script in the left pane and the Python interpreter in the right pane.

My workflow is that I make changes to the Python script, <kbd>CTRL-C C</kbd> it (so that the updated changes are send to the REPL) and move to the REPL (<kbd>CTRL-O</kbd>) so test the updated code. It would be nice if I could make changes to my test case on the left, move to the right REPL screen and execute the updated test case.

Is there a way of running pytest test cases from the REPL or within the script as opposed to spawning a shell and running the pytest command?

**EDIT**: As an aside, I did try using the `main` function from pytest and calling it in the script but for some funny reason, the changes are not picked up unless I kill the old REPL and start a new one. This doesn't happen with other Python script so I'm sure this is related to pytest. Here is the code:

```
def test_add():
  assert myadd(1, 2) == 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pytest.main()
```

Comment: I believe pytest.main() is not testing what you have inside the REPL because it launches the regular py.test runner, which tries to load tests from an expected tests folder and following whatever naming conventions

Comment: @Conrad.Dean: I think it's not about the REPL. I was under the impression that pytest would pick up the latest code for my script before running the test. But it seems that test code once loaded is never reloaded irrespective of the change made to the test script. Really strange...

Answer (score 0):

Following comment of @Conrad.Dean. Seems putting tests into some pytest.py is a kind of useful convention. Below an example illustrating the role of `if __name__ == '__main__'`:

```
def myadd(first, second):
    return first + second

def test_add():
  assert myadd(1, 2) == 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("Running test_add")
  test_add()
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. The `print` gets executed but the test cases are not run by pytest. :(

Comment: and besides, won't you lose all of pytest's assert rewriting and other testrunning goodness?